# "Get Started" button and "Persistent Menu" not showing up for Messenger ONLY account

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

The **Get Started** button and the **Persistent Menu** is not showing if the user registered for Messenger with a phone number, without a Facebook account. I know that I can't get profile information ([error code 2018218](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/)), but from the documentation I have not found anything about the properties `get_started` and `persistent_menu` of the Messenger Profile API. Has anyone encountered such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. From the Facebook developer console, go to your app Settings -> Advanced, in the **App Restrictions** section set "References Alcohol" to **NO** and "Age Restriction" to **Anyone(+13)**.